# bad_command >>filename 2>&1 work in terminal but still prints output to stdout in a script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to learn how to write bash scripts and I cannot produce the desired results. according to everything I've read my code should work and when I test it out in the terminal it works how I want it to but when I test the script out it still prints the output. It stores the output to a file but I don't want it to print. I am at a loss

The script works with the apt package manager

```
elif [ $input = "3" ]; then  
    echo "enter package name"  
    read package  
    apt-get build-dep $package  
    apt-get install $package -y  2>&1 >> /var/log/installlog  2>&1 
    exitstatus=$(echo $?)  
    if [ $exitstatus = "0" ]; then  
        figlet Installation Successful  
    else  
        figlet Failure   
        echo "check /var/log/installlog"  
        figlet check now?  
        echo "y or n"  
        read input2   
            if [ $input2 = "y" ]; then  
                cat /var/log/installlog  
            fi;  
    fi;
```

Ok thanks to @ott this problem was solved! The problem had nothing to do with redirecting. The reason the output was still coming on the screen was the line before the one I was redirecting.

Comment: `>foo 2>&1` and `2>&1 >foo` are two different things.

Comment: `exitstatus=$?`; the command substitution to run `echo` is unnecessary.

Comment: Also, in general, questions here should be cut down to the **minimum necessary to reproduce a problem**. Here, that's probably just the one `apt-get install` line itself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and/or http://sscce.org/

Comment: Are you sure these messages are not shown by the `apt-get build-dep $package` in the line before? In the following line you have the `2>&1` twice, remove one.

Comment: Sorry I am new to scripting and today is the first time ever going on a forum like this. I'm glad I put the extra though because I learned a couple other things I wasn't expecting. I think it is probably coming from the command in the line before. I'll check things out and post what the issue was. Thanks for the quick response @CharlesDuffy

Comment: BTW, also make a habit of running scripts through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the problems it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: Awesome resource to know about thanks again @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Don't add "SOLVED" to the title. The way to indicate that your problem is solved is to accept an answer.

Comment: no one has answered the question other than in a comment.  maybe you could answer with the solution so I can accept it but when I put the solution as an answer someone deleted it. so officially there is no way for me to say that it is solved. what a welcoming community... @KeithThompson

Comment: The moderator who deleted your answer apparently thought it was incomplete. You should still be able to edit it. Remove the "thank you" and expand on the answer. Ideally it should be useful to someone else who has the same problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson well it will not let me comment or edit it and i find it redundant to keep trying to post it if it can be deleted so that i cannot modify or comment on it anymore.

Comment: I think you're saying that the output (that you're trying to avoid) is coming from the `apt-get build-dep $package` command. Is that correct? If so, can you update the question to show what the output is? You never mentioned that. (The answer you posted apparently can't be undeleted because it was deleted by a moderator.)

Answer (score 0):

You have two `2>&1` in the command; remove the first one.